# How to check element if outside the viewport when transform scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know `getBoundingClientRect()` gets the bounds in view but I found out this won't work if the view got transform scale. Any solution on your part.

```
var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

// Check if it's out of the viewport on each side
var out = {};
out.top = bounding.top >= 0;
out.left = bounding.left >= 0;
out.bottom = (bounding.bottom) > ((window.innerHeight) || (document.documentElement.clientHeight));
out.right = (bounding.right) > ((window.innerWidth) || (document.documentElement.clientWidth));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please drag the square, it got transform scale and rotate on.

```js
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(partial){

    //let's be sure we're checking only one element (in case function is called on set)
    var t = $(this).first();

    //we're using getBoundingClientRect to get position of element relative to viewport
    //so we dont need to care about scroll position
    var box = t[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    //let's save window size
    var win = {
        h : $(window).height(),
        w : $(window).width()
    };

    //now we check against edges of element

    //firstly we check one axis
    //for example we check if left edge of element is between left and right edge of scree (still might be above/below)
    var topEdgeInRange = box.top >= 0 && box.top <= win.h;
    var bottomEdgeInRange = box.bottom >= 0 && box.bottom <= win.h;

    var leftEdgeInRange = box.left >= 0 && box.left <= win.w;
    var rightEdgeInRange = box.right >= 0 && box.right <= win.w;


    //here we check if element is bigger then window and 'covers' the screen in given axis
    var coverScreenHorizontally = box.left <= 0 && box.right >= win.w;
    var coverScreenVertically = box.top <= 0 && box.bottom >= win.h;

    //now we check 2nd axis
    var topEdgeInScreen = topEdgeInRange && ( leftEdgeInRange || rightEdgeInRange || coverScreenHorizontally );
    var bottomEdgeInScreen = bottomEdgeInRange && ( leftEdgeInRange || rightEdgeInRange || coverScreenHorizontally );

    var leftEdgeInScreen = leftEdgeInRange && ( topEdgeInRange || bottomEdgeInRange || coverScreenVertically );
    var rightEdgeInScreen = rightEdgeInRange && ( topEdgeInRange || bottomEdgeInRange || coverScreenVertically );

    //now knowing presence of each edge on screen, we check if element is partially or entirely present on screen
    var isPartiallyOnScreen = topEdgeInScreen || bottomEdgeInScreen || leftEdgeInScreen || rightEdgeInScreen;
    var isEntirelyOnScreen = topEdgeInScreen && bottomEdgeInScreen && leftEdgeInScreen && rightEdgeInScreen;

    return partial ? isPartiallyOnScreen : isEntirelyOnScreen;

};

$.expr.filters.onscreen = function(elem) {
  return $(elem).isOnScreen(true);
};

$.expr.filters.entireonscreen = function(elem) {
  return $(elem).isOnScreen(true);
};

$(function(){

$('#circle1').draggable({   drag: function() {
if ($("#circle1").isOnScreen()) $('.indicator').html('yes its on screen');
else $('.indicator').html('its off screen');
      },});


});
```

```css
.circle{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
}

.circle.big{
transform: scale(2,2) rotate(20deg);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div class="circle big" id="circle1">drag me</div>

<div class="indicator"></div>
Press to enlarge
```

Comment: how about if 5 shapes and just get the position at shape index 3? which is the farthest position. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get what you asking.

Comment: what if the shape position is outside of the view and instead of scrolling using scrollbar, i will scroll using the view. i mean I will touch the view and slide it horizontally or vertically? thanks

Comment: Instead of scrollbar, we will use dragging in the view so we can see the shape. Please help. Thanks

Comment: which scrollbar you meant? you mean div instead of window boundary?

Comment: scrollbar of the div.

Comment: Hello, I need your help again. I am downloading svg and I am using loop. how to do it async, that I will just download the svg that isOnScreen?

Comment: @Joe I guess you better create a new question.

Comment: but if you can just help me, I just want to load in async foreach the shapes that isOnScreen.